# SymPy - replacing fourier of multiplication in convolution

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have an expression in SymPy where I try to change the fourier transform of multiplication (of 2 time-domain functions) to the convolution between the transform of each of them.

I want to change the first element in the following expression to convolution between n(t) and p(t).

`G=FourierTransform(n(t)*p(t), t, k) - 2.0*I*k*FourierTransform(n(t), t)`

A convolution function was defined as:

```
def convolve(f, g, t, lower_limit=-oo, upper_limit=oo):
    tau = Symbol('__some_name__', real=True)
    return integrate(f.subs(t, tau) * g.subs(t, t - tau),
        (tau, lower_limit, upper_limit))
```

and I tried:

```
a, b,c = symbols('a b C', cls=Wild)
G=G.replace(FourierTransform(a*d, b,c), convolve(FourierTransform(a, b,c),
    FourierTransform(d, b,c),t)
```

However it seems that python does not recognize this pattern of the fourier transform since G remained exactly the same...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using variable 'd' in your pattern but did not define it. Try `a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d', cls=Wild)`. The pattern that you have, then, works for me:

```
print(
G.replace(
    FourierTransform(a*d, b, c), 
    convolve(
        FourierTransform(a, b,c),
        FourierTransform(d, b,c),t)))
```

gives:

```
-2.0*I*k*FourierTransform(n(t), t) +
oo*sign(FourierTransform(n(t), t, k)*FourierTransform(p(t), t, k))
```